# filter frequencies in Android App

Tags: c#, android, audio, xamarin.android, frequency

**What i want**

I'm trying to get from live microphone recording in my android app to filter frequencies.

I'm sending (for test) 15khz test sound (10ms duration) every 500ms and in my app i have a counter that should increment for each 15khz test tone, so every 500ms it should increase by one.
Unfortunately it doesn't works.

**The error**

Controlling counter while app's running i see that counter increase sometimes by two or three for each 15khz test sound (every 500ms) or sometimes it doesn't increase at all.

**What i'm doing**

Instantiate AudioRecorder ->

```
int sampleRate = 48000;

bufferSize = AudioRecord.GetMinBufferSize(sampleRate, ChannelIn.Mono,
                                                          Encoding.Pcm16bit); //get the buffer size to use with this audio record

recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic, sampleRate, ChannelIn.Mono,
                                                          Encoding.Pcm16bit, bufferSize); //instantiate the AudioRecorder
```

Then `while(recording)` i'm getting magnitude and foreach magnitude i'm getting frequency ->

```
int freq = (int)max_index * sampleRate / fftResult.Length;
```

then if  `freq == 15000` i'm getting decibel ->

```
double Db = 2 * Math.Log(Math.Sqrt(db_re[i] * db_re[i] + db_im[i] * db_im[i]));
```

and while i'm sending test tones with my macbook in my app i'm trying to filter this frequencies ->

```
if (Db > 19)
```

i'm developing using SONY XPERIA

Thanks in advice!!

Comment: UP! someone can help me?

Comment: UP! no one can answer?